# If sentences with multiple variables

Tags: java, string, if-statement, label

I've been researching and I can't find a solution to a problem that I have here. Here's part of the code:

```
    String p1 = PHORA1.getText();
    String p2 = PHORA2.getText();
    String p3 = PHORA3.getText();
    String p4 = PHORA4.getText();
    String p5 = PHORA5.getText();
    char i1 = p1.charAt(0);
    char i2 = p2.charAt(0);
    char i3 = p3.charAt(0);
    char i4 = p4.charAt(0);
    char i5 = p5.charAt(0); 

if (i1 == '<') {
        ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("src\\img\\yellow.png");
        ok.setIcon(img3);
        ok.setVisible(true);
        ok.setText("");
        ok.setToolTipText("MISTAKE");
    } else {
        ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("src\\img\\ok.png");
        ok.setIcon(img3);
        ok.setVisible(true);
        ok.setText("");
        ok.setToolTipText("RIGHT.");
    }
```

I need to do this 19 times (although in the code I only showed 5 variables of each type in order to make it shorter here, but they're actually 19). There is exactly the same statement in the condition, the only thing that changes is the variable.

The rest of the variables' names are p6,p7....p19 and i6, i7.....i19.
Is there a faster way than copying the exact code 19 times?

Comment: Does every if do the same thing? So for example you would want 19 more if and else but the only thing changing is the "i1"?

Comment: Do you know about loops and arrays?

Comment: I always knew that loops and arrays can be used in these type of situations, i just don't know how

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] p = new String[19];
char[] i = new char[19];
for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
    p[j] = PHORA[j].getText();
    i[j] = p[j].charAt(0);
    if (i[j] == '<') {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

This assumes you have the ability to edit PHORA1...PHORA19 to be an array as well. If not, you could have some problems...

Comment: yes, if i'm not wrong what I have to do is declare and array with the 19 terms, but I see that's already done there in the first line you wrote

Comment: There is no need to declare a new String array 'p'.  PHORA[j].getText().charAt(0); will work just as.

Comment: @user2310289 True, but I was trying to keep it close to the original code so the OP could better see how the arrays replace all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a array of Strings

```
String[] PHORA
```

Then you could loop through the array and then pass the String to a method which takes the first char and does the test.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
    testThis (PHORA[x].getText().charAt(0));
}
```